# create custom profile url nav item buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, buddypress, wordpress-shortcode

i have created and nav item for **orders** page in buddypress and i want to create another one but append url to the last nav item.

The first nav tab item:

```
function profile_tab_orders() {
      global $bp;
      bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
            'name' => 'All orders', 
            'slug' => 'orders', 
            'screen_function' => 'orders_screen', 
            'position' => 40,
            'parent_url'      => bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '/orders/',
            'parent_slug'     => $bp->profile->slug,
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'orders'
      ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_tab_orders' );
 
 
function orders_screen() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'orders_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'buddypress/members/single/plugins' );
}

function orders_content() { 
    echo do_shortcode('[orders]');
}
```

Everything works fine and it can be access via this url:

http://example.com/members/demo/orders

Now, I want to create another nav item or shortcode to display orders completed, order pending... like this.

http://example.com/members/demo/orders/completed

http://example.com/members/demo/orders/pending

I tried this but not working..

```
function profile_tab_orders_completed() {
      global $bp;
      bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
            'name' => 'completed', 
            'slug' => 'completed', 
            'screen_function' => 'completed_screen', 
            'position' => 40,
            'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->orders->slug . '/completed',
            'parent_slug' => $bp->orders->slug,
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'completed'
      ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_tab_completed' );
 
 
function completed_screen() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'completed_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'buddypress/members/single/plugins' );
}

function completed_content() { 
    echo do_shortcode('[orders-completed]');
}
```

Can someone suggest me a solution or help me in how to access pending, completed via this url

/**orders**/completed

/**orders**/pending

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any can can help me please??

Comment: Adding nav and subnav items: https://gist.github.com/shanebp/5d3d2f298727a0a036e5